# How to setting Eddystone beacon broadcast (3m or 70m)?

Tags: android, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

How to setting Eddystone beacon broadcast (3m or 70m). I find can do that but I can't see how to đo that in google [beacons](https://developers.google.com/beacons/overview)

Answer (score 1):

The Google Beacon Platform does not have a concept of the transmitter range of beacons.  Many beacon models that support Eddystone, like Radius Networks' [RadBeacon Eddystone Edition](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/collections/all/products/eddystone-devkit?gclid=CjwKEAjw-vewBRDH1-b52Lig1hkSJACTPfVFclm3L9d9fnDRcMID5fUmOt0QrKWisN4EMQWtweFLdhoCDcLw_wcB), allow you to configure their transmitter power from a low setting (a range of just a few meters) to a high setting (a range of 50 meters or more).

As far as Google's registration database goes, the concept of the transmitter power just isn't there.   It allows you to register a latitude, longitude and a floor, but not a radius of transmitter range.   From a Google perspective, it doesn't really matter exactly how far a beacon can be detected -- it's all pretty close anyway.

Full disclosure: I am Chief Engineer at Radius Networks.

Comment: I got that. Thanks you very much !

Comment: davidgyoung, you beacon of your company can support for ios app scan background beacons eddystone.

Comment: Our beacons with eddystone support also transmit iBeacon, which triggers in the background within a couple of seconds on iOS.  Once triggered, background detection of eddystone is also very rapid.

Comment: See my full answer to your question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162149/background-beacon-detection-and-notification-both-ios-and-android-for-eddyston

Comment: can the transmission also be on a schedule. i.e 10am to 10pm transmit and standby/rest during other hours.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I am unaware of commercially available beacons that have such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

David's dead on: When you get a beacon from company X, it'll have a "provisioning" application that configures and prepares the beacon for transmitting.

Part of that will be to set things like beacon IDs, URLs, beacon transmission frequency (1x a second? 10x a second?), and transmit power (otherwise known as TxPower) which is the strength of the radio signal. Stronger and more frequent signals mean your beacon will be seen much farther away.

However, they can **significantly** affect battery life. Some beacons will go from years of battery life down to months depending on the settings. So, you'll want to plan your deployments and settings carefully when provisioning and depoying beacons.