# Background beacon detection and Notification (Both iOS and Android) for Eddystone beacon?

Tags: altbeacon, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

Can we detect beacons in app background(Both iOS and Android). I see Eddystone beacon have some problem with background of iOS. How can solve that ?

Answer (score 6):

iOS does allow background detection of service advertisements like Eddystone, but **Eddystone detection times can be slower than iBeacon**.  The reason iBeacon detections are faster is because **Apple has optimized it with hardware filters**.   Hardware filter slots in the bluetooth chip are activated when you monitor an iBeacon region on iOS.  This causes iBeacon detections to happen within about 2 seconds when an app is in the background, provided hardware slots have not been used up.

You can **get the similar rapid detection of Eddystone** beacons by using **[beacons that interleave both](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/04/21/max-beacon-regions-ios.html) an iBeacon transmission and an Eddystone transmission** and making your app look for both.  The iBeacon detection will wake up your app very rapidly in the background, and once active it will be able to receive Eddystone advertisements immediately thereafter.

You can read more about how bluetooth hardware detection slots affect iBeacon detection times [here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/04/21/max-beacon-regions-ios.html)

Full Disclosure:  I am Chief Engineer at Radius Networks which makes beacons that interleave both iBeacon and Eddystone transmissions.

Comment: Good answer!  We've actually seen iBeacon detection take up to like 30-40s in the background, but it's definitely orders of magnitude better than simple Core Bluetooth background, which waits for the once-every-fifteen minute bluetooth wakeup.

Comment: Does the first-in-last-out mean that if 2 apps have tried to register 30 regions combined. My app will only be able to get in the "best effort group"?

Comment: Yes, that is what our tests suggest.

Comment: What about the situation where the App is even not in the background ? Does IOS allow 
 background detection of service advertisements like Eddystone ?

Comment: No, Apple does not allow auto-launching the app on scan detections of a peripheral (beacon or otherwise).  The closest you can get are (1) auto-launching an app based on re-establishing a BLE connection to a previously connected device (which could be an Eddystone beacon) or (2) auto-launching an app based on iBeacon detection.  The second option is why folks sometimes use dual beacons that advertise iBeacon and Eddystone.